# Magento order data not getting using observer event from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, adminhtml, sales-order

I want item's data in observer from particullar order which order place from admin.
following `config.xml`

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <test_module_after_order>
                    <class>Test_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>orderAfterAdmin</method>
                </test_module_after_order>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

following `Observer.php`

```
public function orderAfterAdmin($observer)
{
    Mage::log("orderAfterAdmin");
    try
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $productIds = array();
        Mage::log("In orderAfterAdmin");
        Mage::log($observer);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        Mage:log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I placed order from admin panel at that time I got

> User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back 
>   in ..\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3937

error massege when `Mage::log($observer)` occur. system.log print In `orderAfterAdmin` but not next step.